# Скрыть колонку при ресайзе в bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12  col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vehicula ipsum non leo tristique eget facilisis lacus commodo. Curabitur vitae justo lorem, non ornare nibh. Pellentesque pretium, tellus ac ultrices faucibus, nibh mauris dapibus lorem, vitae
      viverra nisl elit sit amet libero. Nam eu blandit risus.
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> Phasellus imperdiet mattis nulla. Integer gravida imperdiet congue. Proin vitae pretium augue. Donec est sem, mattis et blandit ac, blandit at arcu. Donec tempus tincidunt suscipit. Suspendisse eu vulputate lacus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-lg-6">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vehicula ipsum non leo tristique eget facilisis lacus commodo. Curabitur vitae justo lorem, non ornare nibh. Pellentesque pretium, tellus ac ultrices faucibus, nibh mauris dapibus lorem, vitae
      viverra nisl elit sit amet libero. Nam eu blandit risus.
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> Phasellus imperdiet mattis nulla. Integer gravida imperdiet congue. Proin vitae pretium augue. Donec est sem, mattis et blandit ac, blandit at arcu. Donec tempus tincidunt suscipit. Suspendisse eu vulputate lacus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

При подключении bootstrap 4 текст разбивается на 2 колонки. Как сделать, чтобы при сжатии, например, к col-md вторая колонка пропадала и оставалась только первая.

Comment: Добавить второй колонке класс `hidden-md-down`

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [`.d-{breakpoint}-{value}`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).

Если хотите скрыть на `xl, sm, md`, то используйте `.d-none .d-lg-block`, что означает, что блок скрыт на разрешении `xl, sm, md`, но показан на `lg`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vehicula ipsum non leo tristique eget facilisis lacus commodo. Curabitur vitae justo lorem, non ornare nibh. Pellentesque pretium, tellus ac ultrices faucibus, nibh mauris dapibus lorem, vitae
      viverra nisl elit sit amet libero. Nam eu blandit risus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- Hide on xs, sm, md, but Shown on lg and xl -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-light">
    <p>
      Phasellus imperdiet mattis nulla. Integer gravida imperdiet congue. Proin vitae pretium augue. Donec est sem, mattis et blandit ac, blandit at arcu. Donec tempus tincidunt suscipit. Suspendisse eu vulputate lacus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Табличка видимости.**

```
Screen Size        |  Class
-------------------+-------------------------------
Hidden on all      | .d-none
Hidden only on xs  | .d-none .d-sm-block
Hidden only on sm  | .d-sm-none .d-md-block
Hidden only on md  | .d-md-none .d-lg-block
Hidden only on lg  | .d-lg-none .d-xl-block
Hidden only on xl  | .d-xl-none
Visible on all     | .d-block
Visible only on xs | .d-block .d-sm-none
Visible only on sm | .d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none
Visible only on md | .d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none
Visible only on lg | .d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none
Visible only on xl | .d-none .d-xl-block
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Укажите блоку который необходимо скрыть классы `.d-md-none .d-lg-block` это означает, что на разрешении от 768 до 991 блок будет скрыт, начиная от 992 - будет виден.
2. Либо используйте медиа запросы для управления блоками `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)`