# Не срабатывает класс visible в Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

Не работают классы `visible-md` и `visible-lg`.
Мне нужно скрыть меню, классы добавил, но вот оно не скрывается на разрешениях мобильных устройств. *Почему так?*

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Меню */

#header {
  background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top;
  height: 747px;
}

.nav ul {
  margin-top: 32px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav__main_menu_list {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-right: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

.nav__main_menu_list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__main_menu_list a:hover {
  background: #386075;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 13px 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__main_menu_phone img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav__main_menu_phone {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: right;
}

.nav__main_menu_list:nth-child(5) {
  padding-right: 0;
}


/* Конец Меню */

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 27px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.heading span {
  font-size: 51px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.heading__img {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 110px;
}

.advantages h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 77px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.advantages__list {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 356px;
  width: 360px;
}

.advantages__list h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.advantages__img_left {
  background: url(../img/advantages_left.png) no-repeat center center;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.advantages__img_top {
  background: url(../img/advantages_top.png) no-repeat center center;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.advantages__img_right {
  background: url(../img/advantages_right.png) no-repeat center top;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.advantages__line {
  background: url(../img/advantages_line.png) no-repeat center center;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.advantages__list p {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

#first {
  background: url(../img/first.png) no-repeat center top;
  min-height: 790px;
}

.move h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.move blockquote {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.move p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.move_two {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 160px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

.move_two_up img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  top: -16px;
}

.move_two_down img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  bottom: -16px;
}

.move_two p {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.move_two h3 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}

.move_three h2 {
  font-size: 37px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.move_three p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.move_three a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 24px 33px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.move_three_button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.transport__service h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#four {
  background: url(../img/four.png) no-repeat center top;
  height: 866px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.transport__service_img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.transport__service_img_left {
  margin-top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-right: -95px;
}

.transport__service_img_right {
  margin-top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -95px;
}

.transport__service_img_top {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3
}

.transport__service_block_up {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 235px;
  width: 770px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -70px;
  position: relative;
}

.transport__service_block_up h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.transport__service_block_up p {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.transport__service_block_down {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 144px;
  width: 770px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.transport__service_block_down p {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.transport__service_block_down_img {
  background: url(../img/down.png) no-repeat center center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 355px;
  top: -35px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.move_four_button a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #23aae2;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #23aae2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 24px 33px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.move_four_button {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.comments__right_arrow {
  float: right;
}

.comments__heading h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}

.comments__left_arrow {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 56px;
}

.comments__left_avatar {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.comments__left {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.comments__left_top_up {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.comments__left_top_up_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.comments__left_top_up_VK {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #23aae2;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.comments__left_top_up_address {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #23aae2;
  margin-left: 140px;
}

.comments__left_down {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.comments__right_arrow {
  margin-top: 156px;
}

.slyder__circyles {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 85px;
}

.slyder__circyles span {
  margin-right: 7px;
}

#six {
  background: url(../img/five.png) no-repeat center top;
  height: 730px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}

.six__heading h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.six__heading h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.six__heading_img {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.six__form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.six__form_input {
  width: 370px;
  height: 67px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #30c2ff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.six__form_button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 67px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #e0bf99;
}

#footer {
  background: #23aae2;
}

.footer__protect a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer__policy a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer__phone img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.footer__phone {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.footer__protect {
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.footer__policy {
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 visible-md visible-lg">
          <div class="nav">
            <ul class="nav__main_menu">
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">Главная</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">О компании</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">ВНЖ и ПМЖ в Болгарии</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">Контакты</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="nav__main_menu_phone">
            <img src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="icon"> +7 (495) 12-321-345<br> +7 (495) 12-321-345
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 heading">
        <h1>Болгария<br>
          <span>ждет Вас</span></h1>
        <div class="heading__img">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/heading.png" alt="d"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 advantages">
        <h2>Наши преимущества</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="advantages__list">
          <div class="advantages__img_left">

          </div>
          <h3>Надежность</h3>
          <div class="advantages__line">

          </div>
          <p>
            Мы всегда придем к вам на помощь <br>в решении самых неоднозначных<br> вопросов
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="advantages__list">
          <div class="advantages__img_top">

          </div>
          <h3>Достоверность</h3>
          <div class="advantages__line">

          </div>
          <p>
            Достоверность - главный принцип<br> нашей работы. Мы знаем все тонкости переезда в Болгарию и оформления соответствующих документов
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="advantages__list">
          <div class="advantages__img_right">

          </div>
          <h3>Компетентность</h3>
          <div class="advantages__line">

          </div>
          <p>
            Наши специалисты с большим опытом работы помогут разобраться во всех юридических тонкостях переезда<br> на ПМЖ в Болгарию
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="first">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="move">
          <h2>Переезд в Болгарию</h2>
          <blockquote>«Если Вам не нравится то место, где вы находитесь -<br> смените его, Вы же не дерево»</blockquote>
          <p>Джим Рон</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="move_two">
          <div class="move_two_up">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/move_two.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <p>Пришло время и перед Вами стоит вопрос</p>
          <h3>Как переехать в Болгарию на ВНЖ или ПМЖ?</h2>
            <div class="move_two_down">
              <a href="#"><img src="img/move_two.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="move_three">
          <h2>Мы знаем ответ</h2>
          <p>Подберем для Вас оптимальный вариант и предложим лучшие условия!
          </p>
          <div class="move_three_button">
            <a href="#">Узнать больше</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="four">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="transport__service">
          <h2>
            Недвижимость и транспортные услуги
          </h2>
          <div class="transport__service_img">
            <div class="transport__service_img_left">
              <img src="img/transport__service_img_left.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="transport__service_img_top">
              <img src="img/transport__service_img_top.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="transport__service_img_right">
              <img src="img/transport__service_img_right.png" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="transport__service_block_up">
            <h3>Мечтаете о доме на солнечном берегу?</h3>
            <p>
              Или хотите выгодно инвестировать в заграничную недвижимость? В любом случае -<br> подходящий вариант уже ждет Вас! Большой выбор объектов жилой и коммерческой<br> недвижимости и профессиональный сервис позволит провести сделку с<br> удовольствием
              и получить нужный результат
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="transport__service_block_down">
            <div class="transport__service_block_down_img">

            </div>
            <p>
              Если Ваши чемоданы уже собраны и Вы готовы к переезду, рады предложить Вам транспортные услуги по перевозке личный вещей в Болгарию. Для успешного размещения на новом месте жительства мы поможем перевести Ваши вещи в сохранности
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="move_four_button">
            <a href="#">Узнать больше</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="five">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="comments__heading">
          <h2>
            Отзывы наших клиентов
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="comments__left">
          <div class="comments__left_arrow">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/comments_left.png" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <div class="comments__left_avatar">
            <img src="img/comments__photo.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="comments__left_top_up">
          <span class="comments__left_top_up_name">Диана Апасова</span>
          <span class="comments__left_top_up_VK">VK.COM/A.APASOVA</span>
          <span class="comments__left_top_up_address">Москва - София</span>
        </div>
        <div class="comments__left_down">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="comments__right_arrow">
          <a href="#"><img src="img/comments_right.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="slyder__circyles">
          <span><img src="img/circyle_left_right.png" alt=""></span>
          <span><img src="img/circyle_top.png" alt=""></span>
          <span><img src="img/circyle_left_right.png" alt=""></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="six">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="six__heading">
          <h2>Есть вопросы<br> по переезду в Болгарию?</h2>
          <h3>Мы проконсультируем <br>вас бесплатно!</h3>
          <div class="six__heading_img">
            <img src="img/six_ellipse.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <div class="six__form">
          <form action="#">
            <input class="six__form_input" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
            <input class="six__form_input" type="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
            <input class="six__form_input" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон">
            <input class="six__form_button" type="submit" value="Заказать консультацию">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="footer__logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="footer__protect">
          <a href="#">2016 / Все права защищены </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="footer__policy">
          <a href="#">Политика конфиденциальности</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="footer__phone">
          <img src="img/footer_phone.png" alt="icon"> +7 (495) 12-321-345<br> +7 (495) 12-321-345
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Не помогло.. Вообще не понимаю в чем причина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что сейчас в **Boostrap 4.*** нету классов `.visible-md` и `.visible-lg`. Последний раз они встречались в *альфа версии*. Есть только два `visible` и `invisible`.

Но чтобы сделать так как Вы хотите есть [специальная утилита](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) для адаптивной верстки.

Поэтому чтобы скрыть блок на мобильных устройствах, но показывать его на таблетах и других более крупных Вам нужно указать такие классы: `d-none d-md-block`.

*P.S. Можно даже сказать, что это дубликат [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793193/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B2-bootstrap-4/793281#793281).*

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)